# Self-signed certificate for Standalone Datasnap Server

Tags: delphi, ssl, https, certificate, datasnap

i have a standalone datasnap server running on my home pc, so it is a Windows 10 standard, not a server edition.

It works perfectly with standard HTTP calls, both when i call it from browser or from an android client (i use a no-ip dynamic dns). Now i would like to switch from HTTP to HTTPS, i dropped a TDSCertFiles component on server, and i tried to generate a self-signed certificate using OpenSSL using this command:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes -out mycert.crt -keyout mykey.key -subj "/C=XX/ST=xxxx/L=xxxx/O=Security/OU=IT Department/CN=mydomain.ddns.net"
```

I copied the 2 SSL dll files inside the server's exe location.
I set both CertFile and Key file (i tried to set RootCertFile too), but when i call server through HTTPS from my client it fires this exception on server:

```
'Error accepting connection with SSL. error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number'.
```

Can someone help me to undertand why?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Seems that you are using incompatible versions of Open SSL libs. Try with these DLLs which are specially built for Indy. See if you get the same result: https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I am already using the DLLs you linked me for the Datasnap server, but i generated the self-singed certificate using another version of OpenSSL, that was the problem! I tried to generate another certificate using the Fulgan SSL too and now it works perfectly! Thanks!